# What happens to a SQL job if it doesn't finish?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-job

Let's say there's a SQL job that runs a stored procedure every one minute.

What happens, if it takes more than a minute? Does it start the procedure again (having 2 of them running in the same time) or it waits for the previous to finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A job can only have the status of running or not, a job that is already running won't start again.